# Weird mouse/keyboard freezups when using PowerPoint 2007 with IBM/Lenovo docking station

Tags: keyboard, mouse, microsoft-powerpoint, thinkpad

I'm not sure what part of my system is responsible for this, but when using PowerPoint, I have problems when trying to resize drawing objects. I'll be dragging the handle and suddenly, the object will deselect and whatever is behind the object will select and start moving around. Next thing I know, the keyboard won't type anymore, and the only way to fix it is to unplug the USB and plug it back in.

In case it's hardware related, I'm using an IMB Thinkpad T60P in a docking station. My keyboard is a Microsoft Natural Keyboard Pro. My OS is Windows XP SP3.

I've never noticed this happening in anything besides PowerPoint, and I don't know anyone else who has this problem (even people with similar setups).

Any ideas what it could be?

**Edit**

Well, it looks like I only get the problem if I plug the mouse into my docking station's USB. If I plug directly into the laptop's USB, everything works fine. And, again, this problem is only with PowerPoint. I tried playing with some drawing objects in Word and had no issue no matter where my mouse was plugged in.

I should also mention I tried a different mouse (a standard Microsoft corded mouse instead of my Logitech trackball), but that made no difference. So, I don't think it's anything specific with the trackball or the trackball's driver.

I tried searching Google but came up empty, so I'm guessing this problem is something unique to my setup.

If you have any thoughts or ideas to try, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like it's something to do with my docking station. If I plug my mouse directly into my laptop (rather than into the dock's USB), I don't have any problem.